# Twig Template Asset Resolution

Tags: symfony, assets, twig

I'm having problems with my child twig templates properly resolving their assets.

My assets lie in web/bundles/mlbp/images|js|css

In my parent twig template that all my other templates inherit from I have something like:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/mlbp/js/jQuery.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

When looking at source this resolves properly to /bundles/mlbp/js/jQuery.js

But in one of my child templates I'm doing something like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{parent()}}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/mlbp/js/tableSortInit.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

This for some reason resolves to /js/tableSortInit.js which does not exist. I don't see why it would work in one but not the other so any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try checking any other templates that relate to that one, it may be coming from those especially if you do a lot of in template rendering etc.

Comment: This was exactly it, I forgot another template and that fixed it